# auto create entries for all email addresses in BBDB3

Tags: emacs, gnus, bbdb, bbdb-3

Does [`bbdb3`](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/bbdb) have something similar to `bbdb/mail-auto-create-p` from `bbdb2`?

Basically I just want `bbdb` to be big brother and auto-create entries
for every email address I ever see. Ever.

**Bonus points**: do this on a per account basis (e.g. I want to add all emails ever seen on an email sent to my work address, but not necessarily my personal address).

Comment: I wansn't aware of the rewrite. Thanks. :)

Comment: Assuming I want to decide manually, what function do I call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
(bbdb-mua-auto-update-init 'gnus 'message)
(setq bbdb-update-records-p 'create)
```

For additional options, the variable bbdb-update-records-p has some nice documentation (C-h v bbdb-update-records-p).

To limit how you create records, you can look at bbdb-accept-message-alist and bbdb-ignore-message-alist. For instance, to avoid recording addresses for messages to your home address, you could try:

```
(setq bbdb-ignore-message-alist '((("To" "CC") . "email@home")))
```